# DocumentApp.openById() fails with "Service unavailable"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm sure I must be doing something silly, but I'm not seeing what it is.  How can I get the contents of a simple text file?  Does it need a .txt extension perhaps?  Perhaps it has something to do with how the file was created over a year ago?

The error was: 'Service unavailable: Docs (line 61, file "fileFuncs")'.  Line 61 is highlighted below.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
function testGetFile()
{

getFile("testGetFile", "WhoAmI");

}

function getFile(calledFrom, targetFile)
{

var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
var files=root.getFiles();
var numFiles=0;

 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   numFiles++;
   var filename = file.getName();


    if (filename == targetFile) {

      Logger.log("Success.  Found file: " + filename);
      Logger.log(' Number of files processed = '+numFiles+'\n\n');

      var fileId = file.getId();
      **var doc = DocumentApp.openById(fileId);       // Line 61:THIS FAILS with above error**
      var body=doc.getBody();
      var text=body.getText();

      Logger.log('text = '+text);// there it is         

      return text;
    }   

   } // while()

return -1;
}
```

Comment: It just occurred to me...  does this require use of the new google sheets?  I hope not.

Comment: did you test what kind of file you retrieved? with something like: Logger.log(file.getMimeType()). In your code you are trying to open a google document, but you tagged your post with the google spreadsheet tag and you are talking about a txt file 0_o txt can be opened with driveapps, google doc with documentapp and spreadsheet by spreadsheetapp

Comment: Thanks for the tip on getMimeType... it reports, Mime Type: text/plain.  I tagged it with google spreadsheet because the script is running inside a spreadsheet.  So, according to your comment I'm opening it properly, yes?

Comment: I suppose I should also mention that the google-scripts tag is no longer available, so google-spreadsheet was the closest I could find.  I'm open to suggestions on other tags I should have used to tag this properly.  Finally, it may be worth pointing out that this text file was created with DocsList.getRootFolder.createFile - I originally opened it with DocsList.files[fileNum].getContentAsString()... but after getting permissions problems on files I created and of course owned... I decided to switch gears and start using DriveApps as recommended by another post I saw here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we know it's a text/plain doc we can add the good method to handle it. As Serge said in it's post the method you are using is only valid for "google document" files so you must check that's a google document file before using it. We are going to do the same but with text/plain documents:

```
function testGetFile(){
  getFile("testGetFile", "WhoAmI");
}

function getFile(calledFrom, targetFile){
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var files=root.getFiles();

  /*
  instead of a root getFiles() I prefer to use searchFiles
  I'ts less work for your script.
  the documentation on search: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters
  */
  files = root.searchFiles("title = 'WhoAmI' and mimeType = 'text/plain'"); // if it's a txt doc it should have .txt at the end of it's title: "WhoAmI.txt"
  var numFiles=0;

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    numFiles++;
    var filename = file.getName();
    var mime = file.getMimeType();
    Logger.log(mime); // produce a lot of output

    if (filename == targetFile && mime=="application/vnd.google-apps.document") {

      Logger.log("Success.  Found GOOGLE DOC file: " + filename);
      Logger.log(' Number of files processed = '+numFiles+'\n\n');

      var fileId = file.getId();
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(fileId);       // this won't fail anymore (I hope)
      var body=doc.getBody();
      var text=body.getText();

      Logger.log('text = '+text);// there it is         

      return text;
    }
    else if(filename == targetFile && mime=="text/plain") {
      Logger.log("Success.  Found TXT file: " + filename);
      Logger.log(' Number of files processed = '+numFiles+'\n\n');
      var text = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      Logger.log('text = '+text);// there it is         

      return text;
    }
  } // while()  
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: This works great when run as-is.  Thank you!  And thank you for the pointer to the docs!  There is a new, related problem which persists even before the above corrections.  Briefly, the call to DriveApp.getRootFolder() fails with a permission problem when the above function is used as part of a library.  I was thinking to start a fresh thread for it, but the only difference is:           function testGetFile()
{

PT.getFile("WhoAmI");

}
The exact error message:  Execution failed: You do not have permission to call getRootFolder.  My script, my folder, my file, my drive... Why no permission?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the methods you use when the condition is true only apply to Google documents and will fail if you try to use them on other file types.

To prevent that simply add a second condition in your code like this :

```
if (filename == targetFile && file.getMimeType()=="application/vnd.google-apps.document") {
```

with the above modification you won't get errors anymore but there is a chance you won't be able to open the target you tried because it was not the right mime type.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm confused though.  According to Harold,"txt can be opened with driveapps".  As I mentioned in my comment to Harold a minute ago, the mime type reports as "text/plain".   But you've stated that "the methods you use when the condition is true only apply to Google documents and will fail if you try to use them on other file types".  So, this contradicts what Harold has stated, leaving the question... What is the proper way to  open a text document?  Could it be failing because it doesn't have a  .txt extension?  Thank you for help!

Comment: See Harold's answer that shows clearly how to get txt files content. I was talking about DocumentApp that only applies to Google docs.